# PlayConsole error: You must provide a default URL for your instant app APKs

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, rollout, google-play-console

I need to  prepare an Alpha testing for an Instant App and It run like a charm on Android Studio but It is failing when I try to roll-out it in the PlayStore, saying:

You must provide a default URL for your instant app APKs

The app structure is done using three modules:

-**base**: It contains all the code

-**apk**: Wrapper to obtains the installable apk

-**instantApp**: Wrapper to obtain the instantApp apk

This are the build.gradles:

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    buildTools = '25.0.2'
    compileSdk = 25
    minSdk = 23
    versionCode = 10
    versionName = '4.0'
    supportLib = '25.3.1'
    playServices = "10.2.6"
}
```

**base/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildTools

    baseFeature = true

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
        versionCode rootProject.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.versionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            [...]
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            [...]
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            [...]
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    [...]
}
```

**apk/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildTools

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId “…”
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
        versionCode rootProject.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.versionName
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            [...]
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            […]
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            […]
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':base')
}
```

**instantApp/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildTools

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation project(':base')
}
```

And this are the Manifests files

**base/Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package=“…”>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
[…]

<application
    android:name=“[…].TrgApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=“[…].LauncherActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="[...]" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="[…].RootActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

    <activity
        android:name="[…].OnBoardingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

    <activity
        android:name="[…].LocationPickerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="[…]" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
        android:value="id:[…]" />

</application>
</manifest>
```

**apk/Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="..." />
```

This package is different that the app's one

Any kind of idea could be awesome

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You must also add the default-url in the Manifest as a meta-data :

```
<activity
    android:name=“[…].LauncherActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:host="[...]" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
      android:name="default-url"
      android:value="https://[...]" />
</activity>
```

Reference : https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/prepare.html#default-url

Comment: That link contains no reference to default urls anymore.  Could you explain why it's still a requirement, and what the default url does?

Comment: Also why is it inside the activity, not for the entire application?  I can't seem to find any documentation for this.

Comment: I contacted Google Play about the broken link and they confirmed that they are updating the documentation. And they actually included a link to this answer in their response as solution.

Comment: Any updates on this? I still can't find any updated documentation regarding "default-url" even though the mentioned error still pops up in Play Console

Comment: Still not updated in the google-play-instant documentation.

Comment: 2024, this is still not documented, but required. Unbelievable.